# Download File with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a problem downloading file, I have two URL´s the first URL content the user and pwd, the second URL content the path of the file that i require.

If only put the second URL appear a error message. I am begginer in VBScript.

*only i want download file*

this is my code, but i dont know if is correct.

```
Function Main       
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate "url/sf_security_check?j_username=myuser&j_password=mypwd" '-- First URL     
Call Extrae_Arc

End Function

Function Extrae_Arc
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "url" '-- second URL
End Function
```

Thanks for help me

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The *IE* object is redefined in *Extrae_Arc* function, hence overrides pointer assigned previously. 
I'd use next scenario:

```
'...
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
Call Main
Call Extrae_Arc
'...

Function Main
  IE.Visible = False
  IE.Navigate "url/sf_security_check?j_username=myuser&j_password=mypwd" '-- First URL
End Function

Function Extrae_Arc
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "url" '-- second URL
End Function
```